# Plotting occurrences frequency as letters height in a stacked barchart

Tags: python, plot, sequence, bioinformatics, consensus

In a list (positions as index) of dictionary (letters as keys) I have:

```
Position 0
L 458 6.81
K 238 3.54
A 676 10.06
T 738 10.98
G 390 5.8
N 190 2.83
! 8 0.12
S 798 11.87
D 137 2.04
M 76 1.13
R 222 3.3
F 168 2.5
Q 297 4.42
I 333 4.95
P 916 13.63
H 102 1.52
C 46 0.68
E 184 2.74
V 619 9.21
W 25 0.37
Y 101 1.5


Position 1
G 419 6.23
S 822 12.23
P 1019 15.16
A 719 10.7
N 239 3.56
F 154 2.29
! 6 0.09
M 75 1.12
T 637 9.48
V 524 7.8
Q 359 5.34
R 207 3.08
L 449 6.68
C 36 0.54
E 191 2.84
Y 90 1.34
K 268 3.99
I 246 3.66
H 101 1.5
D 145 2.16
W 16 0.24


Position 2
K 285 4.24
L 358 5.33
S 906 13.48
E 165 2.45
R 257 3.82
M 63 0.94
G 395 5.88
A 657 9.77
V 788 11.72
T 896 13.33
W 27 0.4
C 48 0.71
H 106 1.58
Q 251 3.73
F 204 3.03
P 578 8.6
D 135 2.01
I 288 4.28
Y 128 1.9
N 187 2.78


Position 3
S 3869 57.56
T 2845 42.32
I 1 0.01
K 1 0.01
A 1 0.01
V 3 0.04
G 2 0.03


Position 4
L 479 7.13
E 297 4.42
F 177 2.63
V 479 7.13
D 153 2.28
K 280 4.17
S 1107 16.47
P 488 7.26
A 629 9.36
T 731 10.87
W 40 0.6
R 224 3.33
I 239 3.56
Y 131 1.95
Q 409 6.08
N 189 2.81
G 442 6.58
M 83 1.23
C 51 0.76
H 89 1.32
! 5 0.07


Position 5
T 632 9.4
R 154 2.29
S 1067 15.87
Q 310 4.61
L 400 5.95
N 180 2.68
E 262 3.9
A 935 13.91
P 725 10.79
G 531 7.9
Y 115 1.71
V 433 6.44
W 27 0.4
H 108 1.61
K 178 2.65
C 43 0.64
D 174 2.59
M 72 1.07
F 163 2.42
I 191 2.84
! 22 0.33


Position 6
E 290 4.31
A 606 9.02
S 1093 16.26
F 189 2.81
R 202 3.01
I 197 2.93
G 511 7.6
T 658 9.79
K 237 3.53
H 103 1.53
L 412 6.13
P 615 9.15
M 75 1.12
! 37 0.55
Q 369 5.49
V 452 6.72
C 36 0.54
D 198 2.95
N 283 4.21
W 35 0.52
Y 124 1.84
```

I want:

[image]

The plot above represents the frequency (field 3 in the data above) of each letter at a given position. The height of the letter encodes the frequency.

I know how to make things like this:

[image]

But I have no idea of something more or less straightforward to make the same thing but with letters and variable height.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is your data structure? A list of dictionaries? How is `Position 1` etc. coded in this list? Please provide an exact sample of your data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the type of plot you're looking for is [sequence logo](http://users.fred.net/tds/lab/sequencelogo.html). There is [an online application to create such sequence logos](http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/logo.cgi), but they start from a multiple alignment or sequence file. You have frequency data, so we will to need to create our own.

First install the necessary packages:

```
git clone https://github.com/saketkc/pyseqlogo.git
pip install biopython==1.77 # biopython 1.78 no longer has Bio.Alphabet
```

You say your data structure is a list of dictionaries but you post some flat text in your question. So first I'll have to do some preprocessing.

```
>>> data = """Position 0
L 458 6.81
K 238 3.54
A 676 10.06
T 738 10.98
G 390 5.8
N 190 2.83
! 8 0.12
S 798 11.87
D 137 2.04
M 76 1.13
R 222 3.3
F 168 2.5
Q 297 4.42
I 333 4.95
P 916 13.63
H 102 1.52
C 46 0.68
E 184 2.74
V 619 9.21
W 25 0.37
Y 101 1.5


Position 1
G 419 6.23
S 822 12.23
P 1019 15.16
A 719 10.7
N 239 3.56
F 154 2.29
! 6 0.09
M 75 1.12
T 637 9.48
V 524 7.8
Q 359 5.34
R 207 3.08
L 449 6.68
C 36 0.54
E 191 2.84
Y 90 1.34
K 268 3.99
I 246 3.66
H 101 1.5
D 145 2.16
W 16 0.24


Position 2
K 285 4.24
L 358 5.33
S 906 13.48
E 165 2.45
R 257 3.82
M 63 0.94
G 395 5.88
A 657 9.77
V 788 11.72
T 896 13.33
W 27 0.4
C 48 0.71
H 106 1.58
Q 251 3.73
F 204 3.03
P 578 8.6
D 135 2.01
I 288 4.28
Y 128 1.9
N 187 2.78


Position 3
S 3869 57.56
T 2845 42.32
I 1 0.01
K 1 0.01
A 1 0.01
V 3 0.04
G 2 0.03


Position 4
L 479 7.13
E 297 4.42
F 177 2.63
V 479 7.13
D 153 2.28
K 280 4.17
S 1107 16.47
P 488 7.26
A 629 9.36
T 731 10.87
W 40 0.6
R 224 3.33
I 239 3.56
Y 131 1.95
Q 409 6.08
N 189 2.81
G 442 6.58
M 83 1.23
C 51 0.76
H 89 1.32
! 5 0.07


Position 5
T 632 9.4
R 154 2.29
S 1067 15.87
Q 310 4.61
L 400 5.95
N 180 2.68
E 262 3.9
A 935 13.91
P 725 10.79
G 531 7.9
Y 115 1.71
V 433 6.44
W 27 0.4
H 108 1.61
K 178 2.65
C 43 0.64
D 174 2.59
M 72 1.07
F 163 2.42
I 191 2.84
! 22 0.33


Position 6
E 290 4.31
A 606 9.02
S 1093 16.26
F 189 2.81
R 202 3.01
I 197 2.93
G 511 7.6
T 658 9.79
K 237 3.53
H 103 1.53
L 412 6.13
P 615 9.15
M 75 1.12
! 37 0.55
Q 369 5.49
V 452 6.72
C 36 0.54
D 198 2.95
N 283 4.21
W 35 0.52
Y 124 1.84"""
```

Not all positions have an equal number of letters, so add the missing ones with frequency 0. Also divide by 100 to get a number between 0 and 1.

```
>>> keys = ['L', 'K', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'N', '!', 'S', 'D', 'M', 'R', 'F', 'Q', 'I', 'P', 'H', 'C', 'E', 'V', 'W', 'Y']

>>> all_scores = []
>>> for position in data.split('\n\n\n'):
      lines = position.splitlines()[1:]
      scores = [(line.split()[0], float(line.split()[-1]) / 100) for line in lines]
      if len(scores) != len(keys):
        scores += [(key, 0.0) for key in keys if key not in [s[0] for s in scores]]
      all_scores.append(scores)

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(all_scores)
[[('L', 0.0681),
  ('K', 0.0354),
  ('A', 0.10060000000000001),
  ('T', 0.10980000000000001),
  ('G', 0.057999999999999996),
  ('N', 0.028300000000000002),
  ('!', 0.0012),
  ('S', 0.11869999999999999),
  ('D', 0.0204),
  ('M', 0.0113),
  ('R', 0.033),
  ('F', 0.025),
  ('Q', 0.044199999999999996),
  ('I', 0.0495),
  ('P', 0.1363),
  ('H', 0.0152),
  ('C', 0.0068000000000000005),
  ('E', 0.0274),
  ('V', 0.09210000000000002),
  ('W', 0.0037),
  ('Y', 0.015)],
 [('G', 0.0623),
  ('S', 0.1223),
  ('P', 0.1516),
  ('A', 0.107),
  ('N', 0.0356),
  ('F', 0.0229),
  ('!', 0.0009),
  ('M', 0.011200000000000002),
  ('T', 0.09480000000000001),
  ('V', 0.078),
  ('Q', 0.053399999999999996),
  ('R', 0.0308),
  ('L', 0.0668),
  ('C', 0.0054),
  ('E', 0.028399999999999998),
  ('Y', 0.0134),
  ('K', 0.039900000000000005),
  ('I', 0.0366),
  ('H', 0.015),
  ('D', 0.0216),
  ('W', 0.0024)],
 [('K', 0.0424),
  ('L', 0.0533),
  ('S', 0.1348),
  ('E', 0.0245),
  ('R', 0.0382),
  ('M', 0.009399999999999999),
  ('G', 0.0588),
  ('A', 0.0977),
  ('V', 0.11720000000000001),
  ('T', 0.1333),
  ('W', 0.004),
  ('C', 0.0070999999999999995),
  ('H', 0.0158),
  ('Q', 0.0373),
  ('F', 0.030299999999999997),
  ('P', 0.086),
  ('D', 0.020099999999999996),
  ('I', 0.042800000000000005),
  ('Y', 0.019),
  ('N', 0.0278),
  ('!', 0.0)],
 [('S', 0.5756),
  ('T', 0.4232),
  ('I', 0.0001),
  ('K', 0.0001),
  ('A', 0.0001),
  ('V', 0.0004),
  ('G', 0.0003),
  ('L', 0.0),
  ('N', 0.0),
  ('!', 0.0),
  ('D', 0.0),
  ('M', 0.0),
  ('R', 0.0),
  ('F', 0.0),
  ('Q', 0.0),
  ('P', 0.0),
  ('H', 0.0),
  ('C', 0.0),
  ('E', 0.0),
  ('W', 0.0),
  ('Y', 0.0)],
 [('L', 0.0713),
  ('E', 0.044199999999999996),
  ('F', 0.0263),
  ('V', 0.0713),
  ('D', 0.022799999999999997),
  ('K', 0.0417),
  ('S', 0.16469999999999999),
  ('P', 0.0726),
  ('A', 0.09359999999999999),
  ('T', 0.10869999999999999),
  ('W', 0.006),
  ('R', 0.0333),
  ('I', 0.0356),
  ('Y', 0.0195),
  ('Q', 0.0608),
  ('N', 0.0281),
  ('G', 0.0658),
  ('M', 0.0123),
  ('C', 0.0076),
  ('H', 0.0132),
  ('!', 0.0007000000000000001)],
 [('T', 0.094),
  ('R', 0.0229),
  ('S', 0.15869999999999998),
  ('Q', 0.0461),
  ('L', 0.059500000000000004),
  ('N', 0.0268),
  ('E', 0.039),
  ('A', 0.1391),
  ('P', 0.1079),
  ('G', 0.079),
  ('Y', 0.0171),
  ('V', 0.0644),
  ('W', 0.004),
  ('H', 0.0161),
  ('K', 0.0265),
  ('C', 0.0064),
  ('D', 0.0259),
  ('M', 0.010700000000000001),
  ('F', 0.0242),
  ('I', 0.028399999999999998),
  ('!', 0.0033)],
 [('E', 0.0431),
  ('A', 0.0902),
  ('S', 0.16260000000000002),
  ('F', 0.0281),
  ('R', 0.0301),
  ('I', 0.029300000000000003),
  ('G', 0.076),
  ('T', 0.09789999999999999),
  ('K', 0.0353),
  ('H', 0.015300000000000001),
  ('L', 0.0613),
  ('P', 0.0915),
  ('M', 0.011200000000000002),
  ('!', 0.0055000000000000005),
  ('Q', 0.054900000000000004),
  ('V', 0.0672),
  ('C', 0.0054),
  ('D', 0.029500000000000002),
  ('N', 0.0421),
  ('W', 0.0052),
  ('Y', 0.0184)]]
```

The `!` is not present in any of the [default colorschemes](https://github.com/saketkc/pyseqlogo/blob/master/pyseqlogo/colorschemes.py), so we add it to the `hydrophobicity` one.

```
>>> colorscheme = {
    'R': 'blue',
    'K': 'blue',
    'D': 'blue',
    'E': 'blue',
    'N': 'blue',
    'Q': 'blue',
    'S': 'darkgreen',
    'G': 'darkgreen',
    'H': 'darkgreen',
    'T': 'darkgreen',
    'A': 'darkgreen',
    'P': 'darkgreen',
    'Y': 'black',
    'V': 'black',
    'M': 'black',
    'C': 'black',
    'L': 'black',
    'F': 'black',
    'I': 'black',
    'W': 'black',
    '!': 'black'
}
```

Now plot the sequence logo:

```
>>> from pyseqlogo.pyseqlogo import draw_logo
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300
>>> fig, axarr = draw_logo(all_scores, colorscheme=colorscheme) 
>>> fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: sequence logo]

Comment: Shouldn't the data be transformed into bits of information in order to obtain something similar to the plot given in the original post?

Comment: @bli could you explain more what you mean by "something similar to"?

Comment: @Synthase I mean with different heights: Maximum height when there is only one amino-acid, minimum when all are equally represented. But looking closely at your example, this seems yet something different.

Comment: Looking at the [pyseqlogo documentation](https://github.com/saketkc/pyseqlogo/tree/master#default-mode-is-bits), it seems that you can get the format that @bli is referring to by setting the `data_type='bits'`.

Comment: @Bli sorry I have truncated the picture to make it simple but strictly talking you have a log scale on y-axis in the figure from my post. So it is just the same thing that BioGeek explained but with a pre-processing using that log scale.

Comment: Just a heads-up that the [author](https://github.com/saketkc) of `pyseqlogo` [let me know](https://github.com/saketkc/pyseqlogo/pull/3#issuecomment-730391972) that part of `pyseqlogo` was exported to [`dmslogo`](https://github.com/jbloomlab/dmslogo) which is better maintained.